# converting numbers into timecode in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, conversion, timestamp

I have a column with a bunch of two 4 digits.

1. 1354 1356
2. 1402 1421
3. 1431 1452
4. 1532 1546
   ... and so on

I've been trying to convert these to look more like

1. 13:54 ~ 13:56
2. 14:02 ~ 14:21
3. 14:31 ~ 14:52
4. 15:32 ~ 15:46
   ...

I've tried wildcard but it's too simple to handle that. I couldn't find a function nor was I successful with date/time format. I'm not sure if I should learn VBA for that.

Comment: Use MID() function and concatenation.

Comment: have a try and share us what you get.. We'll help you till you get it.. /(^_^)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Nested REPLACE(), Note start from the right:

```
=REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(A1,8,0,":"),5,1," ~ "),3,0,":")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A combination of CONCATENATE and MID will help. Of course this is a text function so end results are Text.

[image]

Comment: As a small suggestion, perhaps consider adding a text version of the command to your answer. It might be a minor inconvenience, but copying and pasting is often simpler than trying to type a long command out from a screenshot with two separate windows open.